# How to access JSON response in go?

Tags: go, https

Me making a JSON request

```golang
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", myPath, nil)
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}

resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}

defer resp.Body.Close()
var j map[string]interface{}
err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&j)
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}
```

Now this is returning a `map[string]interface{}`

but the actual shape of the data in JSON is:

```json
{
  key1: "string"
  key2: "string"
  key3: [
   { key1: "string", key2: "int", key3: "Array<string>" },
   { key1: "string", key2: "int", key3: "Array<string>" },
   ...a lot more
  ] 
}
```

How can I actually get the the key3 data?

```golang
for key, value := range j {
  if key == "key3" {
    // Im stuck here, 
  }
}
```

I have tried unmarshalling the json response into a struct as well as decoding it as that struct

```golang
type key3Struct struct {
  key1 string
  key2 string
  key3 []string
}

type ResponseStruct struct {
  key1 string
  key2 string 
  key3 []key3Struct
}

// Attempt 1
j = ResponseStruct{}
json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&j)
==> error cant convert map[string]interface{} to ResponseStruct{}

// Attempt 2
json.Unmarshal(resp.Body, &j)
==> it looks like [ {} ] no data in it...
```

Comment: Use structs if you can. Note that `Attempt 2` fails because your fields are unexported (i.e. they begin with a lowercase letter); and `Attempt 1` fails because you are trying to assign to `j`, which is of type `map[string]interface{}`, a value of type `ResponseStruct`, and that's simply not allowed, you should update the type of `j` in its declaration.

Comment: @mkopriva This was my issue thanks!!! :) I also had to do `json:"keyName"` to fix it completely.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @mkopriva for the help my issue was two things:
1 - I didn't have Capitals for the struct props
2 - I didn't declare them as json

Solution:

```golang
type key3Struct struct {
  Key1 string `json:"key1"`
  Key2 string `json:"key2"`
  Key3 []string `json:"key3"`
}

type ResponseStruct struct {
  Key1 string `json:"key1"`
  Key2 string  `json:"key2"`
  Key3 []key3Struct `json:"key3"`
}
```